# How to re-write SQL query so it acts more like a Left Outer Join

Tags: sql

I have the following query

```
SELECT 
  SCHEDULEPARTS.SCHEDULEID,
  SCHEDULEPARTS.LINE_NO,
  SCHEDULEPARTS.PARTID,
  SCHEDULEPARTS.QUANTITY,
  SCHEDULEPARTS.PRINT,
  PART.PART_NUMBER,
  PART.DESCRIPTION AS PART,
  PART.PRICE,
  PARTBINLOC.BIN_LOCATION
FROM
  SCHEDULEPARTS
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PART ON (SCHEDULEPARTS.PARTID = PART.PARTID)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PARTBINLOC ON (PART.PARTID = PARTBINLOC.PARTID)
WHERE
  SCHEDULEPARTS.SCHEDULEID = :SID AND 
  PARTBINLOC.BRANCHID = :BID
ORDER BY
  SCHEDULEPARTS.SCHEDULEID,
  SCHEDULEPARTS.LINE_NO
```

If the part (PARTID) doesn't have a bin location in the PARTBINLOC table, nothing at all is returned, because of the Where clause. The company has 3 branches and each part should have a bin location record for each Branch.

So part id 1 should have a bin location for branch 1, another for branch 2 etc. If a bin location doesn't exist for the current branch, I want ScheduleParts and the Parts record information to be returned with a blank bin location.

Is this possible and how would I write the SQL?

Comment: The problem is that in an outer joined row `PARTBINLOC.BRANCHID` is null, so `PARTBINLOC.BRANCHID = :BID` dismisses that row and turns your outer join into an inner join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The restriction in the `WHERE` clause on the `PARTBINLOC` table belongs in the `ON` clause of the respective join:

```
SELECT 
    sp.SCHEDULEID,
    sp.LINE_NO,
    sp.PARTID,
    sp.QUANTITY,
    sp.PRINT,
    p.PART_NUMBER,
    p.DESCRIPTION AS PART,
    p.PRICE,
    pbl.BIN_LOCATION
FROM SCHEDULEPARTS sp
LEFT OUTER JOIN PART p
    ON sp.PARTID = p.PARTID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PARTBINLOC pbl
    ON p.PARTID = pbl.PARTID AND
       pbl.BRANCHID = :BID
WHERE
    sp.SCHEDULEID = :SID
ORDER BY
    sp.SCHEDULEID,
    sp.LINE_NO;
```

Note that you might want to take advantage of table *aliases* to make your query more terse and easier to read.